# How to disable back navigation after app reaches home page of the app in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I am using One Activity, many fragments in my android app.

[image]

I have One Main Activity with Navhost. And 3 Fragments.
fragment1 as home fragment which is starting point of navigation. 
fragment1 navigates to fragment2, 
fragment 2 navigates to fragment3.

From fragment3, it navigates to home fragment i.e, fragment1.

After reaching from fragment 3 to fragment 1, if I back press in fragment1, it is again navigating to fragment3 instead of exiting the app.

How should I disable the back navigation from home fragment to fragment3.

I've used 
                            `navController.navigate(navController.getGraph().getStartDestination());`

in the fragment3. Not working.

Comment: try to first clear back stack fragment  and then jump to fragment one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57336381/4390987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked.

`navController.popBackStack(R.id.fragment2,true);
 navController.popBackStack(R.id.fragment3,true);
 navController.navigate(navController.getGraph().getStartDestination());`

Comment: well this works but this goes back to the first fragment still holding the fragments viewmodel data.

Answer (score 0):

Because fragment 3 is still alive.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finishAffinity();

}
```

Comment: `finishAffinity()` exits my app irrespective of the fragment I'm in. There is only one activity in my app. I've written this code in the activity. @NimaKhalili